# Add a hook to Sentry Logback to scrub data

Tags: scala, logback, sentry

I'm using the Logback SDK for Java to send events to Sentry as described in the [documentation](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/java/guides/logback/).

Snippet:

```
<conversionRule conversionWord="CUSTOM_CONVERSION_RULE"
                converterClass="clazz..." />
...
<property scope="context" name="myEnc" value="%d{ISO8601,UTC} | %-5level | %-50thread | %-55logger{55} | %CUSTOM_CONVERSION_RULE" />
...
<appender name="SENTRY" class="io.sentry.logback.SentryAppender">
    <dsn>...</dsn>
    <encoder>${myEnc}</encoder>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>ERROR</level>
    </filter>
</appender>
....
```

The initial problem was that the events sent to Sentry were not converted by my custom conversion rule. All the other appenders such as Console that use the property `myEnc` containing the conversion rule parse the data as expected. But it seems that the `io.sentry.logback.SentryAppender` in combination with the `encoder` somehow doesn't do that. The filter property is working as well as the dsn one, so I get the errors in Sentry but not with my custom parsing.

The version that I use for `io.sentry.sentry-logback` (and transitively `sentry`) is `1.7.24`.

I then read about `before-send` hook from Sentry docs which is what I want to control what data is sent to Sentry and I had to upgrade to latest for that which is `3.1.3` at the time of writing this.

The Logback XML config changed a bit:

```
<appender name="SENTRY" class="io.sentry.logback.SentryAppender">
    <options>
        <dsn>...</dsn>
        <beforeSend>????</beforeSend>
    </options>
    ...
</appender>
```

From what I can see the `before-send` hook is exactly what I need to scrub the data when required because I don't want some info to be sent to Sentry. [docs](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/java/guides/logback/configuration/options/#before-send)

Now, the second issue is that I don't know how to ref here a method. In the Java config there is a BiFunction that takes the event and can alter it. But I want to apply this hook to all my log events, that's why the only place it is configured is in the Logback SDK.
In Spring Boot for example there is a starter for Sentry and, off course, a bean that you can inject in the auto-configuration.
But, I'm using Scala with no Spring Boot.

Also, the project is already in prod so I cannot change lots of things and I'm looking for the smallest one that will allow me to add a hook to Logback's SDK for Sentry.

Here is the [appender](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java/blob/main/sentry-logback/src/main/java/io/sentry/logback/SentryAppender.java#L39) and it looks like (I'm not sure how it works) the `options` can be populated from XML and than pass to `init` that will take all them into account, including my before send hook.

I don't know if it's accepted to have two questions and only one referenced in the title but I didn't find a nicer way to ask/explain the problem, because one thing lead to another.

To summarize the questions:

1. Why that custom rule is not working with Logback Sentry's appender.
2. How can I let the appender know about my hook and use it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Best way to go about this is to disable the auto-init via the appender, and call Sentry.init via code. There you can write your callback programatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure Sentry independently from appender configuration in `logback.xml`. For example:

```
public class Main {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);

    static {
        Sentry.init(options -> {
            options.setDsn("PUT YOUR DSN HERE");
            options.setBeforeSend((sentryEvent, o) -> {
                sentryEvent.setTag("custom", "tag");
                return sentryEvent;
            });
        });
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LOGGER.error("oops");
    }
}
```

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="sentry" class="io.sentry.logback.SentryAppender" />
    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="console"/>
        <appender-ref ref="sentry"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Check complete code sample in github repo: https://github.com/maciej-scratches/sentry-logback-custom-config